# Battery level retrieval in hybrid app for Android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, batterylevel

Im developing an Hybrid app which will get batter level and alerts if its 100 %.
Trying it in Worklight..Can any one please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What? I don't understand what you want

Comment: Hi Macro..
I am trying to develop an Hybrid mobile App for android using worklight.
For that i want to retrieve battery level, if the level is 100%(Full) . I want to alert the user with a pop up.
Is there a way in Hybrid apps to retrieve battery percentage..

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn and understand how to create Cordova plug-ins in Worklight: [Adding native functionality to hybrid apps with Apache Cordova](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova)

Once you've mastered that, you can search online for Cordova plug-ins that do what you're looking for, and implement it in your Worklight app based on what you've learned above.

Here is one such plug-in:

- [Cordova plugin battery status](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status)